# "I'm too lazy to do my homework" questions

Tags: support, question-quality

I just saw this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437686/child-process-runs-uptime-every-3-seconds-in-c

This is far from the first "I'm too lazy to do my homework" question I've seen.  I feel that these questions are horrible and that they degrade what's left of SO's quality.  I try to downvote and vote to close these.

I spend a bit of time thinking about whether the question is "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" or a "why is this code broken" question, but they're really none of these.  They're narrow enough.  It's plenty clear that the poster just wants his homework done.  There's no code provided, so it can't be a "why is this code broken?" question.

What's the "right" close reason for these?

Comment: I VTC'ed as unclear.